# Do we still need Multi Level Password Hash if Brute Force is not a matter

Tags: hash, password-hashing

I am developing a web application where user can SignUp and all that kind of stuff. I was doing some research about Hashing and Storing passwords in Database and came across [this article](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence#title.2).

In this article, the author at some extent prefer to Multi Hash Password before storing into database as

```
$stored = password_hash(
    base64_encode(
        hash('sha256', $_POST['password'], true)
    ),
PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


if (password_verify(
    base64_encode(
        hash('sha256', $_POST['password'], true)
   ),
   $stored
 )) 
 {
      // Success :D
 } else 
 {
      // Failure :(
 }
```

You can see that the Author hashing the password into 3 steps

```
1) Hashing Password with sha256
2) Base64 Encoding the above generated Hash (to avoid null bytes or whatever reason)
3) And then Using some stronger hashing algorithms to make it even harder to break
```

so, my question is suppose there is a scenario where I only allow the user with only 10 invalid login attempts with invalid password and if the user is still not logged in with valid password then the user is temporarily disallowed to login. And there is no other way to login.

I mean is there any other reason for such Hashing of passwords other than brute force? What if I block the user after 10 invalid attempts and he cannot do a brute force attack anymore? Will I still need to do such Multi Level Hashing?

To be clear in simple words, Do I still need to do such password hashing like above if I only allow maximum of 10 attempts to invalid passwords?

Comment: You say *Brute Force is not a matter*. Then why are you asking about password hashing?

Comment: @mentallurg because Password Hashing and Brute Force are 2 different things. Please do read the question thoroughly and understand my concerns as fgrieu has done so

Comment: OK, my question was too short :) I mean, that password hashing is *usually* used to prevent brute-forcing. If you don't see any risks that somebody can obtain passwords, why hash them then? Just store passwords as plain text. I don't know any system, where passwords are stored as plain texts, because all of them want to prevent that somebody can see or can restore by brute-forcing the plain passwords. For what purpose do you need password hashing then?

Comment: @mentallurg Yah I got your point. Actually there was some misconception in my mind which Mr. Fgrieu cleared out. After truly understanding, I even find my question so stupid.  And I can understand why you found it strange. Hehehe. But I think that's why we use SE to clear our confusions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there any other reason for such Hashing of passwords other than brute force?

The reason for purposely slow password hashing is to mitigate the risk of brute force password search when the database of hashed passwords leaks. SHA-256 and Base64 are of no great help towards that slowness, as they are rather fast.

Still, the reason for the stack SHA-256 / Base64 / [`password_hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.password-hash.php) / Bcrypt is rational (if messy), and the proposed combination effective.

Using `password_hash` makes it less likely that an application programmer makes a goof, by enforcing a standard interface with important features built-in: cost parameter, random salt, algorithm encoded in the hash to make evolution of the algorithm and cost possible without disruption to users.

Problem is that the best algorithm supported by `password_hash` and found in standard implementations of PHP (as considered by the author, and at the time) is Bcrypt. That's an  iterated password hash with one clear advantage compared to PBKDF2: it uses sizable memory, which significantly raises the cost of GPU, FPGA, and ASIC brute force attacks for a given cost of legitimate use. But it suffers from a silly design limitation to 72 bytes on input, and often of an implementation limitation that stops parsing the input on the first zero byte (plus platform-dependent alphabet, with the combination sometime leading to truncation when dealing with characters that are not printable ASCII).

To solve the 72 bytes limitation (which is an issue with some passphrases, especially with multi-byte characters as used in many cultures), an option is to first SHA-256 the canonical UTF-8 representation of the user passphrase. Problem is, the output of SHA-256 is 32 bytes that each can take any value in [0x00-0xFF], which hits the zero byte issue. Hence Base64:

- SHA-256 quickly turns UTF-8 of any length into 32 bytes, without sizable rick of collision / loss of password entropy;
- Base64 quickly makes that 44 (or so) well defined ASCII characters;
- that's quickly passed to `password_hash` thru a well-defined interface;
- that's quickly passed to Bcrypt in a format that all implementations will consistently process and (purposely slowly) hash;
- `password_hash` soundly formats the outcome and other parameters into some password hash string.

Notice that using Base64 without SHA-256 would solve the character set problem, but exacerbate the length limitation by limiting to 54 bytes. The combo is a minimally ugly workaround to the lack of built-in mitigation to Bcrypt's limitations in its implementation by `password_hash`.

---

Note: the [linked article](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence#title.2) invokes "collisions in the MD5 hash function" in the context of password hashing. I don't see how that's technically relevant; but that's a detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. That cleared too much. Actually I was missing the Main point that Brute Force Attack is only for Leaked Databases. And that's why I had been mentioning this 10 times attempts. You are a Hero.